# Unable to create instance of NopEngine

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I am creating a new theme in nopcommerce,
I want to print all categories in view,

I have wrote follwing code to retrieve all subcategories within a cartegory,

This call(on line 2) fails with `Object reference not set to instance of onject` error.

```
var _engine = new NopEngine();
var categoryService = _engine.Resolve<ICategoryService>();
var L1Categories = from p in categoryService.GetAllCategoriesByParentCategoryId(24)
                    where (p.Deleted==false)
                    select p;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: @SonerGönül My code is valid and it is used in same way in other modules of nopcommerce

Comment: In which location of nopcommerce you have written this portion of the code. Nop engine initialisation only happen at global app start event. Usually, no need to set it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the following code to resolve ICategoryService:

```
var categoryService = EngineContext.Current.Resolve<ICategoryService>();
```

Do not forget to add appropriate "using" directives